# Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable/ExponentialMovingAverage

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Am using TF 1.14.1

```
import tensorflow as tf


v1=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[1]), trainable=False)
v2=tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1]), trainable=False)

ewma =tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.99)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    
    sess.run(ewma.apply([v1]))
```

gives error below:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable/ExponentialMovingAverage
     [[node Variable/ExponentialMovingAverage/read (defined at /hdd/all_cv/ladder/test1.py:13) ]]
```

What's the issue?

Comment: is there supposed to be a gap between `ExponentialMovingAverage` and `(decay=0.99)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have received [FailedPreconditionError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/FailedPreconditionError), which means running an operation that
reads a `tf.Variable` before it has been initialized.

I have replicated your issue in TF 1.x in Google Colab, please refer the same in below

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

v1=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[1]), trainable=False)
v2=tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1]), trainable=False)

ewma =tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.99)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(ewma.apply([v1])))
```

Output:

```
1.15.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

6 frames
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_4/ExponentialMovingAverage
     [[{{node Variable_4/ExponentialMovingAverage/read}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_4/ExponentialMovingAverage
     [[node Variable_4/ExponentialMovingAverage/read (defined at /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'Variable_4/ExponentialMovingAverage/read':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 438, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1451, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 462, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 492, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 444, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-a403f4c0115a>", line 15, in <module>
    print(sess.run(ewma.apply([v1])))
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/moving_averages.py", line 435, in apply
    colocate_with_primary=True)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/slot_creator.py", line 126, in create_slot
    return _create_slot_var(primary, val, "", validate_shape, None, None)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/slot_creator.py", line 74, in _create_slot_var
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1500, in get_variable
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1243, in get_variable
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 567, in get_variable
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 519, in _true_getter
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 933, in _get_single_variable
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 258, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 219, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2519, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 1688, in __init__
    shape=shape)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 1872, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 203, in identity
    ret = gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4239, in identity
    "Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Performed `ewma.apply` op outside of session and resolving its value inside the session. Please refer working code shown below

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

v1=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[1]), trainable=False)
v2=tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1]), trainable=False)

ewma =tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.99)
mv = ewma.apply([v1])  

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    #print(sess.run(ewma.apply([v1])))
    print(sess.run(mv))
```

Output:

```
1.15.2
None
```